# Equal and hashcode in inherited class

Tags: java, jpa

In my understanding, the below implementation of equal and hashcode are safe as the correct method in derived class would invoke (instead of parent), even if I call it through the parent  pointer. Provided the parent is treated as abstract class (uses in JPA - hiberante base class). Please confirm this assumption based on the example below.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
class A {
String type;
}

@Entity
class B extends A {
String uniqueName;
.......

@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
..
}
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
}
}

@Entity
class C extends A {
String uniqueName;
.......
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
..
}
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
}
}

class D {
A a;
String name;
}
```

Since A can accept the instance of both B and C, when writing the equal/hash method for D, is it ok with the above implementation (only in B & C, not in A). there would not be a case where A is instantiated directly (new A).

thanks.

Comment: Which implementations? You merely posted the declarations, not the method bodies.

Comment: using the IDE generated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your example code is incomplete because I suspect you're asking that if the `d.equals()` method uses `a.equals()`, then which version of the `equals()` method gets called?

If that's what you're asking, then the answer would be the `equals()` method of the type of `a`. If `a` is a `B`, then the `B.equals()` will get called. If `a` is a `C`, then `C.equals()` gets called. This is true regardless of whether `A` has its own implementation of the `equals()` method or not.

Since you mentioned Hibernate, I suppose you're trying to create a joined-subclass mapping or some such. If you map it correctly, then Hibernate won't try to instantiate an `A` directly, which should really be abstract anyway, since that's how you described it.

Comment: thanks.. sorry being not clear with my question, but u guessed me right :-)

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking if it is ok to write hashcode and equals methods in a derived class where the immediate superclass doesn't have them implemented?

If you say class A would never be instantiated directly, why not declare A abstract, then there will be no problem.

Comment: Tom, thanks .. Yes that is my question.. not about the implementation...
 I wasn't sure how JPA handles abstract classes.. a quick search show some examples of specifying DiscriminatorColumn too.. I will read more..

Comment: @bsreekanth, when u don't specifically override equals in A, equals() and hashCode() is inherited from Object.

Answer (score 1):

> In my understanding, the below
>   implementation of equal and hashcode
>   are safe as the correct method in
>   derived class would invoke (instead of
>   parent), even if I call it through the
>   parent pointer.

Are you asking for polymorphism? If you do: yes, which method gets called depends on the runtime type, not the type of the reference. As long as your objects are typeof B or C everything is fine.